# Group Event Logs by Date

Tags: powershell

How can I possibly use Get-WinEvent and Group-Object the TimeGenerated to get a similar output

```
3540    2022-12-24
2811    2022-12-23
2088    2022-12-13
1422    2022-11-19
240     2022-11-11
```

The idea is just to figure out which dates had the highest number of events (Be it System/Security - the EventType isn't important). Been prepping for an exam (DFIR) and I'd appreciate a one-liner help. I will obviously study/research the way afterwards.

Comment: `get-winevent application | format-table -GroupBy timecreated`

Comment: Use timecreated.Date to group by the day, otherwise, you are grouping are ticks which is 100nsec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using group-object and sort-object (all my Application logs are the same date, so I used the System log).  The events are contained in the Group property.

```
get-winevent system | group {$_.timecreated.date} | sort count -Descending

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
  390 3/20/2023 12:00:00 AM     {System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Read...
  340 1/11/2023 12:00:00 AM     {System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Read...
  334 4/28/2023 12:00:00 AM     {System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Read...
```

Going through all logs takes more doing, since there's a 256 logname limit to queries.  It took me about 11 minutes.  There's a lot of exceptions for empty logs.

```
get-winevent -listlog * | % { get-winevent @{logname=$_.logname} } |
  group {$_.timecreated.date} | sort count -Descending | select -first 5

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
40371 6/9/2023 12:00:00 AM      {System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader....
 6989 6/1/2023 12:00:00 AM      {System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader....
 6428 6/8/2023 12:00:00 AM      {System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader....
 6067 6/7/2023 12:00:00 AM      {System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader....
 5815 6/5/2023 12:00:00 AM      {System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader....
```

Comment: Thank you jdweng .. Thanks a bunch @js2010 that's it! The idea was to get a lay of the land during intrusion investigations, which days saw the most noise AND I only have PS at my disposal, no SIEM/ELK. Thanks again!